# How can I make this dropdown responsive?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, dropdown

Here is a dropdown and I want to make this like wp. When anyone arrive the dashboard and click on the avatar.Dropdown will show full screen. And when anyone visit this dashboard from pc and click on the avatar. This drop-down size will be 180px.

Here's [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Pogamar_YT/pen/aejbVv) check this out and give me solution.

In media query position relative not working. Please help me out to fix that.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbnpURUI0RXpHWPtUZouzXUDiXme-mFvQDjzuXbeRE3XB5QGKOYg" alt="User Profile">
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Inad Islam</a>
        <a href="#">Edit my Profile</a>
        <a href="">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
.dropdown {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    background: #4796b3;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropbtn img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background: #25a2c1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    disolay: inline-block;
   }
  .dropdown-content {
    min-width: 160px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your media query -- `disolay`.

Comment: "*I described my problem so much*" - where? What does mean "*not working*", describe your expected and actual result.

Comment: eidted. Check now

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.dropbtn').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.dropdown-content').slideToggle();
 });
 });
```

```css
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.dropbtn {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
 
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    background: #4796b3;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
 
.dropbtn img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background: #25a2c1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbnpURUI0RXpHWPtUZouzXUDiXme-mFvQDjzuXbeRE3XB5QGKOYg" alt="User Profile"></button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Inad Islam</a>
                  <a href="#">Edit my Profile</a>
                  <a href="">Log Out</a>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Hope so this will help full for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly by 'responsive' I have come up with a solution.
I removed the `position:absolute` and `left:0` from the `.dropdown-content`. I also removed the typo that you did on your media-query.Try this out.
https://codepen.io/ekinalcar/pen/PMBPMd

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background: #4796b3;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
   }
}
```